# SEO for multifacited company

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, negative-seo

I am trying to create a website and up the SEO rating for rocket-media.co.uk. The company covers a lot of different design, print, exhibition and digital services. They currently have a one-page site but after some tips from a previous post I am thinking of making it into multi-page site and wanted to check that there is a benefit to having mutli-pages over one page/

I also had an idea of multi subdomains and wanted to know if subdomains are better or worse for SEO. So for example print.rocket-media.co.uk, design.rocket-media.co.uk rather than a print and design page within rocket-media.co.uk.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked in various forms on Pro Webmasters, here's one of many that covers some of what your asking in both question and answers provided: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82822/multiple-domains-or-one-new-domain-or-sub-domains-pros-and-cons Another one here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo

Comment: But to save your time searching this and that and trying to get a good idea what's what... Google associates sub domains with main domains if the are linked to one another and the authority does pass down but a tiny fraction is lost in the process, but this amount is so small it becomes unnoticeable and only if you have silly amounts of sub domains would it become more noticable. Your decision should be based on what looks good for your customers. not SEO... adding additional sub domain is not useful for your customers because they have to type `something.before-brand-name.com`. /my 2 cents.

Comment: Also, Google is great at associating niches to one and another... for example most often Google associates Website Design, with Print, Design, Graphic Design and even marketing, SEO  and so on... Google and Bing are not dumb and creating sub domains purely to 'game' SERPS would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The benefits of having multiple pages are all congregated in one word: diversification.

You can be more precise in the topic you will have to develop for each page. Also one of those benefits is the relationships you could create semantically and contextually between the pages. In a world that is being taking over by mobile devices, you will be delivering less scrollable content, improving user engagement and potentially better performance.

As a consequence of having multiple pages, you will be creating opportunities to develop vertical niches as your website grows. If you have a measurement plan, you will be improving the user experience by tracking and analysing the users' behaviour and making those changes accordantly.

In terms of SEO this is a challenge, it will be required to have a top to bottom strategy to create content that will be around a main topic. Then, the inner pages will be considered a supporting idea to the main topic. And so on.

I believe that you now can see that having subdomains is not a good idea if you want to develop niches later on. In the SEO world subdomains are considered separate websites. People have reported several times that their rankings improved once the took the decision to move from a subdomain to a inner folder.

Even though you have a multifaceted business, at the end of they day you serve a broader industry market, and that will be understood by search engines, especially Google.